# how to set the jdbc fetch size for a query in toplink essential?

Tags: jpa, jdbc, toplink-essentials

We have a legacy project in this using oracle essential with version 1.0.0 for persistence. Can you please provide how to give the hint to the query for increasing the JDBC fetch size and how we verify the fetch size in logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the fetch size as query hint

```
query.setHint("toplink.jdbc.fetch-size", "100");
```

Comment: Thanks @simon for the response. is there is a way to verify the JDBC fetch size in toplink essential?

Comment: you should turn on logging then you get some information.